# Smallest $m$ for which $U_m$ has an element of order x?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I am stuck on this question:

What is the Smallest $m$ for which $U_m$ has an element of order 13? Order 17? Order p? (p is prime)

The work I have tried so far:

I thought that maybe the element might be a generator, because they have the highest order in a group of units, but you can prove that in fact the element in $U_m$ with order p is not a generator, because a generator has order $\phi(m)$, and $\phi(m)$ can't be prime (because it is a product).

I don't really know what else to try.

Comment: $\phi(m)$ can be prime: $\phi(4)=\phi(6)=2$. (But those are the only cases.) Are you using $U_m$ as a notation for $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^\times$? Hint: if a finite group contains an element of order $p$, what can you say about the number of elements in that group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* If $p$ is a prime, then $U_m$ has an element of order $p$ iff $p$ divides $\phi(m)$, the order of $U_m$.

Now $\phi(m)= \prod p_i^{e_i-1}(p_i-1)$. Where can $13$ or $17$ or $p$ come from as a divisor of this product?

Comment: But I don't need  $ϕ(m)$ to be 13, I need some element ($a$) in $U_m$ to have  the property: $a^{13} = 1 mod m$

Comment: @JustinSanders, exactly. You need that $13$ divides $\phi(m)$.

Comment: Got it, so I need whichever gives the first result, either $n*13+1$ is prime or $13^2$ might have it. Since I get that 53 is 13*4+1, that is the first result. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinSanders, exactly! Now do the same for $17$.